# How I can make SELECT using DISTINCT and ORDER BY RANDOM at same time?

Tags: django, postgresql, random, django-orm, django-filter

The scenario:

I have a model in a view, I'm using django-filters, so I need make a queryset filtered by django-filters and ordered randomly.

The Issue:
**django-filters adds a DISTINCT to the SQL**, something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ... WHERE ("products_creditcard"."is_active" = True  AND    ("products_creditcard"."bank_id" = 3  OR "products_creditcard"."bank_id" = 1  OR "products_creditcard"."bank_id" = 4 )) ORDER BY RANDOM()
```

But that generates an exception for postgresql:

ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
SQL state: 42P10
Character: 1992

I think may exist any way to add random to the select, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use group by instead of DISTINCT

```
SELECT  ... WHERE ("products_creditcard"."is_active" = True  AND    ("products_creditcard"."bank_id" = 3  OR "products_creditcard"."bank_id" = 1  OR "products_creditcard"."bank_id" = 4 )) ORDER BY RANDOM() GROUP BY fieldName
```

Hope this will work for you

Comment: Tha bad thing is I will need hack django*filters

Answer (score 2):

Use `GROUP BY`, as @Shivam  wrote. But his syntax is invalid.
`GROUP BY` must come before `ORDER BY`. Like this:

```
SELECT p.column1, p.column2, ..
FROM   products_creditcard p
WHERE  p.is_active
AND    p.bank_id IN (1, 3, 4)
GROUP  BY p.column1, p.column2, ..
ORDER  BY random();
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to use nested SQL?

It might not be the best approach, but maybe something like this would work in a pinch:

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   (SELECT DISTINCT ... 
    WHERE 
       ("products_creditcard"."is_active" = True 
          AND("products_creditcard"."bank_id" = 3  
          OR "products_creditcard"."bank_id" = 1  
          OR "products_creditcard"."bank_id" = 4)
   ) AS Source
ORDER BY RANDOM()
```

edit: looking at the other solution on this page (the one about using "group by" in lieu of distinct), I believe that one to be much more elegant than mine.